# PowerBI: related dimensions not working

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to implement the following diagram in PowerBI.

Sales and budget are facts and the other 3 tables are dimensions. As I have multiple facts using the same dimensions, I can't use multiple cross filter direction (see [documentation](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-create-and-manage-relationships/)). The problem I'm seeing is that a filter on product category, does not filter the other dimensions as I would think. A solution is to integrate the product category aspect into the product dimension and let that be dependent on time, but that complicates the dimension, especially if you have multiple things like product categories. Another solution suggested in documentation (link above) is to use two product dimensions, but that is not really an option as that makes the cube impossible to use.

Does anyone have a good solution for this?

[image: Product categories]

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm a bit confused, but why don't you use 2 separate `Time` tables for `Product cat` and `Budget` respectively? Then should be able to use bidirectional filters in table relationships.

Comment: @user5226582 But that won't work, because if I select a specific product category, then that won't affect the time dimension used for budget, and so it won't change the result I see. It will show number for all time and not how the category is set up.

Comment: Can you include your schema, and maybe few sample rows for each table? Enough for a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I realised that I was missing a line from sales to time as well. Data should be really simple: 1 piece of product A sold 1/1 2017, 2 pieces of product B sold 10/1 2017. Then a product group of A starting 1/1 2017 and ending 7/1 2017. If I select this group. I only want to see the product A sold on 1/1 2017.

Comment: First of all you'll have to duplicate your time dimension for each link to avoid circular references. Next to that, if you want dimensions to filter eachother you'll have to work with bi-directional links: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-bidirectional-filtering/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Product cat needs to be moved as a seperate dimension and linked with the facts, then there is no problem.